# how get icon running apps and save in Array_list?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-icons

I want to get icon running apps and showing in listView.
I can get the name of the apps. And I will show in the list view but
I use The following code
Manager.java

```
   public class Manager  {
  //other methods


   public ArrayList<Drawable> getListApp()
{
    my_packge_name=new ArrayList<String>();
    my_packge_icon=new ArrayList<Drawable>();

    PackageManager pm = base_context.getPackageManager();;
    ActivityManager am=(ActivityManager) base_context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) 
    {
        String s=runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName;
        try {
        ApplicationInfo ap= pm.getApplicationInfo(s, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        if( pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ap.packageName) != null ){
            String currAppName = pm.getApplicationLabel(ap).toString();
            Drawable icon=pm.getApplicationIcon(ap);

               my_packge_icon.add(icon);
          //  my_packge_name.add(currAppName);

           //This app is a non-system app
}
    return my_packge_icon;
 }
```

List.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manager);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    arr_icons= new ArrayList<Drawable> (new    Manager(getBaseContext()).getListApp());

    adapter=new Myadapter(getBaseContext());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

in GetView

```
if(convertView==null)
        {
            Holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item_listview,null );
            Holder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            Holder.icon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_icon);
            convertView.setTag(Holder);

        }
        else
        Holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

       Holder.icon.setImageDrawable(arr_icons.get(position));
```

}

error :

```
  Java.lang.NullPointerException.....
```

When the names of all the programs I run correctly.
But when all program icons that I got this error.
I do not know why the array is not initialized.

Comment: Show `Myadapter ` class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `image_icon` belongs to `custom_item_listview.xml`

```
 Holder.icon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_icon);
```

is wrong. It should be

```
 Holder.icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_icon);
```

like for your `TextView`

Comment: Yes you are right saying.
Thank you so much to help

Answer (score 1):

`Holder.icon` is `null`.Try to check the id.